# Bind command to C-RET in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Say I have some interactive function in Emacs `my-function`, how can I bind it to Ctrl + RET?

I have tried with:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-RET") 'my-function)
```

and

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-return") 'my-function)
```

but none of them seem to work. is this at all possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Always remember that `kbd` very conveniently accepts the exact same syntax that Emacs gives you when you *ask* it about a key sequence, so you never ever have to *guess*.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-RET</kbd> tells me:

```
<C-return>
```

therefore I would use `(kbd "<C-return>")`

OTOH, when running Emacs in my terminal, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-RET</kbd> tells me:

```
C-j
```

because `C-RET` isn't a valid control character in a terminal, and therefore Emacs isn't receiving the same input that it gets in GUI mode (so I wouldn't be able to use that binding in my terminal).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. The method in general helped me figure out tricky syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(global-set-key [(control return)] 'my-function)
```

It works for me, but may not in a terminal as per @phils's answer.